# Invoking function before selecting files with angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload to upload files to the server.
[angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

The problem is related to the ng-file-select part:

```
<button ng-file-select="test1($files)" style="overflow: hidden;" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Test">
```

Test

I would like to invoke some function for showing modal popup window before showing a popup window for selecting files.

It means, I would like to invoke some function let's say: preTest() before selecting emails.

Do you have any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found a very nice way how we can do some action before showing selecting dialog popup window.

We can use two elements:
1. One hidden, which I showed in my previous post
2. The second one with e.g. ng-click function where we do what we need to do and then we use:

```
angular.element('selector').trigger('click');
```